# How to create a cone polygon to sample SpatRaster to represent a cameras field of view

Tags: r, terra

I am working with a wildlife camera grid. I would like to extract values from SpatRaster's over the camera points, but from the field of view. To simulate a cameras field of view, I would like to create a cone polygon that is pointed in the listed bearings of the cameras in the grid.

Minimal working example:

```
library(terra)
f <-system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <-rast(f)

WildCams <- spatSample(r,10, "regular", as.points=TRUE)
bearings <- sample.int(180,10)
WildCams$bearings <- bearings    
WildCams_buf <- buffer(WildCams,5000)
WildCams_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(WildCams)
```

The [following answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/215602/88909) provides an example of the type of result I would like to create in R for multiple points. [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/465172/88909) provides an example for creating a cone polygon for a single point to a portion of sphere.

I started working from the example to create a cone around a single point but do not know how to extend this to a grid of points. The following does not work but builds on [this example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/465172/88909):

```
# Attempt 1: Create a cone polygon
theta <- 120 # my angle of interest
radius <- 500 # my radius length of interest (in meters)

WildCams_buf_sf <- sf::st_as_sf(WildCams_buf)
theta = pi*theta/180
cone1 <- vect(WildCams_buf_sf)
conegrid = rast(cone1, nrow=nrow(r), ncol=ncol(r))
conegrid2 = rasterize(cone, conegrid, field="bearings")
conegrid3 <- project(conegrid2, crs(r), res=res(r))

plot(conegrid3)
xy = crds(conegrid3)
xy[,1] = xy[,1] - st_coordinates(WildCams_sf)[1]
xy[,2] = xy[,2] - st_coordinates(WildCams_sf)[2]

v = (atan2(xy[,1], xy[,2]) + theta)

conegrid3[] = (1+sin(v))/2
conegrid4 = mask(conegrid3, vect(WildCams_sfbuf ))
plot(conegrid4 >0.05)
```

Is there a function in terra or another package that creates a field of view cone from a set of points that can individually be set to sample in the orientation of the camera's bearing? I would like to extract SpatRaster values from the field of view cones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**sample data**

assuming we have a data.frame of camera's with ther lon/lat position, camera bearing, camera angle width and camera distance.

```
# sample data with camera coordinates, viewing angle (from north) and viewing distance
cameras <- data.frame(id = 1:2,
                      lat = c(52.0807722,52.0825922), 
                      lon = c(5.8374241, 5.8393871),
                      angle = c(10, 180),
                      width = c(30, 60),
                      dist = c(250, 150))
```

**code**

```
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(geosphere)
library(sfheaders)
library(mapview)  # for viewing purposes only
cameras.sf <- cameras %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326)
# view/verify camera location
# mapview::mapview(cameras.sf)
wedge.func <- function(coordinates, distance, angle, width, id) {
  coordinates.m <- matrix(unlist(coordinates), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = NULL)
  angles <- angle - width/2 + seq(0, width, by = 0.5)
  angle.point <- lapply(angles, function(x) geosphere::destPoint(unlist(coordinates), b = x, d = distance))
  m <- matrix(unlist(angle.point), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
  allpoints <- rbind(coordinates.m, m, coordinates.m)
  wedge <- sfheaders::sf_linestring(allpoints) %>% 
    st_set_crs(4326) %>%
    st_cast("POLYGON")
  return(wedge)
}
# get points of the camera's
point_coords <- split(st_coordinates(cameras.sf), row(st_coordinates(cameras.sf)))
# create wedges
wedges <- dplyr::bind_rows(
  mapply(wedge.func, 
         point_coords, cameras.sf$dist, cameras.sf$angle, cameras.sf$width, cameras.sf$id, 
         SIMPLIFY = FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(id = cameras.sf$id)

# view
mapview(list(cameras.sf, wedges))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks - makes sense. I can work with this. I am surprised that a package has not been made that does this automatically.

Comment: This worked very well for my purposes. I simplified things down a bit in my code but the principles are the same. This will be useful for others working with remote camera arrays looking to extract field of view data from remote sensing layers.